# Paste into specific artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I searched all over but can't find a solution - maybe I'm just not grasping the concept of an artboard quite yet. Here's the issue: **I can't paste into a specific artboard that is not on top (not the first in the list of artboards).** I have tried selecting the artboard in the Artboards panel, Paste in Place, Paste in Front, Paste in Back. Even Paste on All Artboards puts two copies of the object on the **same** artboard.

This is getting a bit frustrating which is why I'm taking to StackExchange. Any help/suggestions/corrections/tips would be appreciated.

*Note: I'm still relatively new to Illustrator.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your artboards are like a canvas , whatever you paste in the bounds of it will show up on it (works just like slices). If artboards overlap then your work will be on both arboards. You can, on the other hand, paste something into a specific **layer** by selecting the layer first.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. It was just a bit confusing to me that selecting an object would change the artboard... is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: Change it to what really? The artboard you are working on will be highlighted. The only impart this has is that the rulers change. You can fix that by using the global rulers.

Comment: Well through my use of artboards so far it's seemed inefficient to have to change the artboard every time I want to say align an object to a specific artboard - as clicking the object always switches the artboard to the one on top.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you; the align to artboard only works for the current artboard it is on.

Comment: See, that's where I'm getting confused - you said in your answer that the object is on both artboards, and now you're saying "the artboard it is on". Not to say you're inconsistent, just that this is my point of confusion.

Comment: Yes its a bit confusing. An object can span from art board to artboard. An dartboards can actually overlap. In this case I think the "higher one" (in the artboard list) gets selected. Think of artboards like slices that can overlap.

Comment: For your workflow it doesn't really matter what artboard is selected unless you want to export it. Objects are not assigned to artboards (unlike with layers). They simply show up on them if they are in bounds.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a bit more sense. But I'd still complain to Adobe about the behaviour of object selection with artboards, that's still not an intuitive decision to me.

Comment: Well, how would you expect it to be? Which artboard should be selected when? I am just curious what other options you see.

Comment: Since (from my current understanding) artboards are more or less separate from the objects themselves (e.g. objects are not 'attached' to any particular artboard), the current artboard that is selected shouldn't change when an object is selected (this current behavior suggests that the object is somehow related a particular artboard which it is not). Unless any object *is* attached to a specific artboard especially if the artboards don't overlap or the object is only on one artboard, I might tolerate this choice, but otherwise...

Comment: Yes and no. Try this: when you select an object by clicking inside an artboard, the artboard gets selected. If you select an object by clicking outside an artbard, the selection remains. So the artboard selection is related to where you click.